# What condition should I write to make everything work

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating an application that simply counts how many hours I am sitting at any case. And when you click on +1 or -1 (although it is not particularly necessary :)) I should have a number displayed accordingly.
Code XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn11"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:text="+1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn21"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtTime1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn21"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="212dp"
        android:text="+1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn31"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn22" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn31"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="+1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn32" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn12"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:text="-1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn22"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn22"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="212dp"
        android:text="-1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn32"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn32"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="-1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtJava"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:text="JAVA"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtTime1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.053"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEng"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="ENGLISH"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtTime2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.062"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMath"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="MATH"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtTime3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.053"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime1"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:text="TIME"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtEng"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime2"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        android:text="TIME"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtMath"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime3"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:text="TIME"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

JAVA Code:

```
package com.example.times;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtJava;
    private TextView txtTime1;

    private TextView txtEng;
    private TextView txtTime2;

    private TextView txtMath;
    private TextView txtTime3;

    private Button btn11;
    private Button btn12;
    private Button btn21;
    private Button btn22;
    private Button btn31;
    private Button btn32;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtJava = findViewById(R.id.txtJava);
        txtTime1 = findViewById(R.id.txtTime1);
        txtEng = findViewById(R.id.txtEng);
        txtTime2 = findViewById(R.id.txtTime2);
        txtMath = findViewById(R.id.txtMath);
        txtTime3 = findViewById(R.id.txtTime3);
        btn11 = findViewById(R.id.btn11);
        btn12 = findViewById(R.id.btn12);
        btn21 = findViewById(R.id.btn21);
        btn22 = findViewById(R.id.btn22);
        btn31 = findViewById(R.id.btn31);
        btn32 = findViewById(R.id.btn32);

        btn11.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btn12.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btn21.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btn22.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btn31.setOnClickListener(listener);
        btn32.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int value1 = 0;
            int value2 = 0;
            int value3 = 0;
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn11:
                    value1+=1;
                    String s11 = String.valueOf(value1);
                    txtTime1.setText(s11);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn12:
                    value1-=1;
                    String s12 = String.valueOf(value1);
                    txtTime1.setText(s12);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn21:
                    value2+=1;
                    String s21 = String.valueOf(value2);
                    txtTime2.setText(s21);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn22:
                    value2-=1;
                    String s22 = String.valueOf(value2);
                    txtTime2.setText(s22);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn31:
                    value3+=1;
                    String s31 = String.valueOf(value3);
                    txtTime3.setText(s31);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn32:
                    value3-=1;
                    String s32 = String.valueOf(value3);
                    txtTime3.setText(s32);
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
}
```

I used case because I thought the code would be shorter, and just to practice using it. I basically understand what's wrong in my code, but I don't understand how to fix it. Here, probably, it is necessary to prescribe a condition, but I do not understand what. Loops are useless here (I just always like to insert loops in the wrong place).

Comment: *I basically understand what's wrong in my code* We don't. You need to tell us. Why do you think it is necessary to prescribe a condition? Why are loops useless here? What are you trying to do? Because we do not know.

Comment: The essence of the application is that when you click on the button, my number either increases by 1 or decreases by 1. Cycles in my opinion are useless, for example for. I create a range i < 100 (i = 0) and it immediately outputs 100. The while cycle will work the same way. Is it rational to write a solution through case?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you're asking, I can help you. In your `onClick` method you need to first attempt to parse the existing value from `txtTime1`, `txtTime2` and `txtTime3`. Then check which button was clicked. Then perform your range validations. And finally set the value back to the text fields. Something like,

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int value1 = 0;
    try {
        value1 = Integer.parseInt(txtTime1.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    int value2 = 0;
    try {
        value2 = Integer.parseInt(txtTime2.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    int value3 = 0;
    try {
        value3 = Integer.parseInt(txtTime3.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn11:
        value1 += 1;
        break;
    case R.id.btn12:
        value1 -= 1;
        break;
    case R.id.btn21:
        value2 += 1;
        break;
    case R.id.btn22:
        value2 -= 1;
        break;
    case R.id.btn31:
        value3 += 1;
        break;
    case R.id.btn32:
        value3 -= 1;
        break;
    }
    value1 = Integer.min(100, value1);
    value1 = Integer.max(0, value1);
    value2 = Integer.min(100, value2);
    value2 = Integer.max(0, value2);
    value3 = Integer.min(100, value3);
    value3 = Integer.max(0, value3);
    txtTime1.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
    txtTime2.setText(String.valueOf(value2));
    txtTime3.setText(String.valueOf(value3));
}
```